# Drag and drop groups of spans to new positions on a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag

I'm new to javascript + jquery, and I'm working on a scheduling tool that iterates over course data, writes current rooms to a table, and creates and positions courses to the table based on the cell's id. All of that works fine, but I'm having trouble with expanding the drag and drop functionality with jquery-ui.

[Please see fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/kerynegan/egcj4qzu/)

Basically, each course has its own unique class assigned to all of the spans in that course (group###), and each span has its own unique id ([abc...]###). If I grab any span, I would like to be able to drop said span, and its siblings in .group### to the new schedule position, (or perhaps move one span, delete its siblings from the old positions, and recreate them in the related positions) but I have NO idea how to go about it. My real code would have courses that span up 7 weeks, but the fiddle includes just 2 for clarity.

Below is the drag and drop jquery (with some commented out ideas).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").on("dragstart", function (event) {
        //var x = $(this).attr('class');
        //var z = $(this).attr('id');
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'))
    });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.type === 'drop') {
            var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
        de=$('#'+data).detach();
        de.appendTo($(this));
        //var x = $(de).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        //var b = $("." + x +":not(:has(" + de +"))");
        //console.log(b);
        };
   });

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to use native drag'n'drop or jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable?

Comment: Either is fine with me, so long as it works. I thought the UI's helper/clones might be helpful, but I haven't figured out how to use them properly.

Comment: Ok, so each `.crse` should  be draggable to an open slots, correct? What is not working?

Comment: I can drag all of them, but I can't grab the first "course 1" span (a100), drop it into Room 2, and force the repositioning of the "course 1" span (b100) to its matching spot in Room 2. I want to be able to drag multiple spans at once to multiple new positions

Comment: Was that not clear? I can update the question. Basically if I drop any of the spans in .group100 to a new position, I want the other spans with the same class to be forced to follow to new positions. If that can't be done, I would like to delete the others in the group, and set some sort of trigger that would call a function to rebuild new versions of the deleted spans in the new position with the same group name.

Comment: Ok, so it's not the drag'n'drop itself, but the position of the dropped item fitting into cell, correct?

Comment: Well, it's really a) how do I drag multiple spans with the same class .group###, and then b) at drop, how do I drop the sibling spans into td cells that are offset by the same distance, especially when that might mean moving each span 2 cells to the left (+2 time blocks) and 4 down (+4 classrooms over) from their original position?

Comment: Or if the relative positioning of the dropped sibling spans is too difficult, I could see an option wherein I would drop the one span to the new position, delete the siblings from their old positions by their .group### class, and then call a function to recreate the siblings, but I'm not sure how to a) delete the siblings in a class but not the span itself or b) add a trigger to a dropped element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sort of a basic example you might like: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

From this, we can make a basic working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".crse").draggable({
    opacity: 0.35,
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: $("#scOut tbody"),
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("filled slot");
    }
  });
  $("td[id^='Room']").droppable({
    accept: ".crse",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      addCourse(ui.draggable, $(this));
    }
  });

  function addCourse($item, $target) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item
        .appendTo($target)
        .fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
tr td:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tr:nth-child(1n+2) {
  height: 50px;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

td:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

td {
  height: auto;
  min-width: 40px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 90px;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 110px;
}

td:nth-child(1n+1) {
  border-right: 2px solid #eee;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(60, 181, 181);
}

tr:nth-child(1) th,
tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(4n),
td.rooms,
td:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

table tr td {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="scOut">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" id="rooms" class="rooms">Room</th>
    <th colspan="4">Week1</th>
    <th colspan="4">Week2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="scw1t1">8:30</th>
    <th id="scw1t2">12:00</th>
    <th id="scw1t3">3:15</th>
    <th id="scw1t4">6:30</th>
    <th id="scw2t1">8:30</th>
    <th id="scw2t2">12:00</th>
    <th id="scw2t3">3:15</th>
    <th id="scw2t4">6:30</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Room 1</td>
    <td id="Room_1scw1t1" class="filled">
      <span id="a100" class="crse group100">Course 1</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Room_1scw1t2" class="filled">
      <span id="a102" class="crse group102">Course 2</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Room_1scw1t3" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_1scw1t4" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_1scw2t1" class="filled">
      <span id="b100" class="crse group100">Course 1</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Room_1scw2t2" class="filled">
      <span id="b102" class="crse group102">Course 2</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Room_1scw2t3" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_1scw2t4" class="slot"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Room 2</td>
    <td id="Room_2scw1t1" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_2scw1t2" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_2scw1t3" class="filled">
      <span id="a103" class="crse group103">Course 3</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Room_2scw1t4" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_2scw2t1" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_2scw2t2" class="slot"></td>
    <td id="Room_2scw2t3" class="filled">
      <span id="b103" class="crse group103">Course 3</span>
    </td>
    <td id="Room_2scw2t4" class="slot"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rgw049r6/1/

If you want to move a group, based on selectors, you can do this, but it's more complex. We can add the group data to the helper in `start` and then append the group in `drop`. Or, you can simply use the dragged item and make the group in `drop` and then append the group.

---

**Update**

As I mention, moving multiple items can be more complex.

Consider this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rgw049r6/6/

We have to detect what changed and target the other items.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".crse").draggable({
    opacity: 0.35,
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: $("#scOut tbody"),
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("filled slot");
      ui.helper.data("source-id", $(this).parent().attr("id"));
    }
  });
  $("td[id^='Room']").droppable({
    accept: ".crse",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      // perform the same for other items in group
      var cs = ui.draggable.attr("class").split(" ");
      var group, tCell;
      var $target = $(this);
      var src = parseId(ui.helper.data("source-id"));
      var trg = parseId($(this).attr("id"));
      $.each(cs, function(k, v) {
        if (v.indexOf("group") === 0) {
          group = v;
        }
      });
      $("." + group + ":not('.ui-draggable-dragging')").each(function(ind, elem) {
        var sID = parseId($(elem).parent().attr("id"));
        var tID = detectChange(sID, trg);
        addCourse($(elem), $("#" + tID.id));
      })
    }
  });

  function addCourse($item, $target, notHelper) {
    console.log("Adding: " + $item.attr("id") + " to: " + $target.attr("id"));
    var me;
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      if (notHelper != true || notHelper == "undefined") {
        $item
          .appendTo($target)
          .fadeIn();
      } else {
        me = $item.detach();
        me.appendTo($target).fadeIn();
      }
    });
  }

  function parseId(s) {
    var results = {
      id: s,
      room: parseInt(s.slice(5, 6)),
      week: parseInt(s.slice(9, 10)),
      time: parseInt(s.slice(11, 12))
    };
    return results;
  }

  function makeId(r, w, t) {
    return "#Room_" + r + "scw" + w + "t" + t;
  }

  function detectChange(s, t) {
    var result = s;
    if (s.room != t.room) {
      result.room = t.room;
    }
    if (s.week != t.week) {
      result.week = s.week
    }
    if (s.time != t.time) {
      result.time = t.time;
    }
    result.id = "Room_" + result.room + "scw" + result.week + "t" + result.time;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Twisty, I truly appreciate the help, and your code is much cleaner than mine. But I don't think this does what I need to it. The fade-out/in isn't  necessary, but the moving of groups is, as each "group" is a full course, with the spans being individual class sections of that course. See edited fiddle with course names: https://jsfiddle.net/kerynegan/rgw049r6/3/. If I move MATH 101 to Room 2 in week 1, MATH 101 in week 2 needs to follow it to Room 2 (or to a new time, or both, whatever the case may be). Right now, I'm still only moving Week 1, which doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks, Twisty. This is great.